# How can I add adjustable current to a DC-DC converter?

Tags: amplifier, dc-dc-converter, converter

I would like to use a DC-DC converter to adjust the voltage and the current too. I would like to use MP2307, XL4015 or something similar what can easily buy.

How to add adjustable current? I dont want to use opamp (like Lm358) because it will be oscillating.

Comment: Do you mean: "I want to switch between constant current and constant voltage mode"? The only way you can fix voltage AND current is if you also fix the load - making the system kinda pointless

Comment: Also, an opamp shouldn't oscillate - one that does just indicates poor design (Loop instability, that has to be fixed by polesplitting and/or other techniques)

Comment: Draw a schematic of what you want. I fear something is getting lost in the language barrier

Comment: I have been donig simple DC/DC with opamps just fine, so your "because it will be oscillating" does make no sense at all.

Comment: **No, I would like to adjustable the voltage and the current too in the same time.** That is physically impossible. The load defines how much current flows when you have a certain voltage, or how much voltage is needed when you push through a specific current. You can't adjust both at the same time, that's impossible.

Answer (score 10):

> I would like to use a DC-DC converter to adjust the voltage and the current too.

> I would like to adjustable the voltage and the current too in the same time.

It doesn't work that way.  A power supply can control one degree of freedom, such as the voltage **or** the current, but not two.  The load determines the other degree of freedom.

For example, if you have a fixed-voltage 5 V supply, you have no say over the current.  If someone connects a 1 kΩ resistor to the supply, then the supply will be forced to (as long as it maintains the output at 5 V) to supply 5 mA.  With a 100 Ω resistor, the current will be 50 mA.

Likewise, a constant-current supply of 100 mA has no say over the voltage.  If you connect a 47 Ω resistor to it, it has to put out 4.7 V to maintain the 100 mA.

What **is** possible is a supply that puts out some fixed voltage or current, *whichever is lower*.  These are actually fairly common, and are sometimes called *current limited* supplies.  For example, a 5 V supply current-limited to 100 mA will put out 5 V when you connect a 100 Ω resistor to it.  That's because the load (the resistor) draws (5 V)/(100 Ω) = 50 mA.  Since (50 mA) < (100 mA), the supply continues to put out the fixed 5 V.

However, let's say you connect a 20 Ω resistor to this supply.  If it maintained 5 V, the current would be (5 V)/(20 Ω) = 250 mA.  That is greater than the current limit of 100 mA.  We know therefore that the supply will switch to constant current mode.  That means the output voltage will drop to (20 Ω)(100 mA) = 2 V.

Answer (score 1):

Many DCDC converter  chips have a current sense resister that is external .This approach is valid when the currents are not too high     .Peak Current mode chips which are common use this resister to sense peak current .If you vary this resister you will have a variable current supply that is not stunningly accurate but is really simple to implement and easy to understand .Often the sense resister has a low value like less than 1 ohm .I have used mosfets as voltage controlled resisters by giving the gate source zero to 10 volts DC via a 10K pot to get manual control.The on resistance of mosfets has a tolerance of say 30% when comparing max to min RDs on .When you   have  a    fixed   series resistance and a fixed parallel resistance       the overall accuracy can be adequate .All mosfets have a positive tempco for RDs on so current tends to fall with increasing temp making your proposed PSU more idiot proof .